# SQLCipher in ios6 Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s (architecture already changed)

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, sqlcipher

I have a problem building **sqlcipher** with **xcode 4.5.2**. Basically I followed the examples at http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-iphone-sqlite-encryption-with-sqlcipher/ and http://sqlcipher.net/ios-tutorial/ . Unfortunately I end up with a message telling me that the ssl lib and the sqlcipher lib are not build for armv7s.

Error message:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/jeven/Library/Developer/<...>/Debug-iphoneos/libsqlcipher.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/jeven/Library/Developer/<...>/Debug-iphoneos/libsqlcipher.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/jeven/Library/Developer/<...>/Debug-iphoneos/libcrypto.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/jeven/Library/Developer/<...>/Debug-iphoneos/libcrypto.a

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
      "_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:
...
```

I know this has been posted a couple of times but I already changed the target architecture for the openssl and the sqlcipher projects, as you can see in the following screen shots.

**openssl:**
[image]
**sqlcipher**:
[image]

I am really kind of stuck here :( Does anyone has a hint for me?

Comment: Stephen Lombardo (sqlcipher) will have a look at it (if it's a bug). Outcome can be traced at: https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher/issues/44

Comment: I have the same issue. I've added my comments to the [post](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher/issues/44). Waiting for an answer. Hopefully Stephen will give some good inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a very similar problem before, try removing the armv7s and leave only the armv7

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer, it seems to work but will it still run on an iPhone 5 (armv7s)? I don't have an iPhone 5 just an iPhone 4s.

Comment: Of course, there are tons of apps on the AppStore that were just built for armv7 and they're working just fine :)

Comment: ... then I guess it's solved :D thanks Ismael (I don't know though why I could'nt find it on google)

Comment: Removing armv7s from sqlcipher didn't do the trick --at least for me. Removing armv7s from the main project doesn't seem to be ideal moving forward. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4):

try set build active architecture only of debug to NO!
[change either config of openssl and sqlcipher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGfeJ.png)

Comment: +1 Setting Build Active architectures to NO on sqlcipher project helped.

Answer (score 2):

Add **libsqlite3.dylib** to **Build Phases**' Liraries List.

Select your project target -> Build Phases:

Add **libsqlite3.dylib** to **Link Binary With Libraries**

Comment: Yes! This was my problem. But I had to add libsqlcipher.a, not libsqlite3.dylib. Note that this question is for SQL cipher. But a very similiar fix, thanks.